# Can't post data along with large file size upload PHP

Tags: php, apache, post, upload

I am trying to upload file along with some data in form. It is working perfectly fine for small files. But, when I am trying to submit data along with large files, it is not capturing data.

This is Form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required placeholder="Title">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="report" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <center>
                <input type="submit" name="upload_report" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn_font">
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST["upload_report"])) {


        echo $_POST['title']; // giving title index undefined



        $max_report_id += 1;
        $target_dir = "Reports/";
        $file_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,trim($_POST['title']));
        $file_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,trim($_FILES['report']["name"]));
        //$file_size = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,trim($_FILES['report']["size"]));
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($file_name); //basename gets filename from path
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $file_type = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $target_file = $target_dir . $max_report_id . "." . $file_type;

        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            //echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        /* Check file size
        if ($file_size > 5000000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        */
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $status_fail = true;
            $fail_message = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["report"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                $status_success = true;
                $success_message = "The file ". $file_title. " has been uploaded.";
                $query = "insert into reports(title,fname,path,platform,added_by,added_on) values ('$file_title','$file_name','$target_file','$platform','$user_id',now())";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die($query);
            } 
            else {
                $status_fail = true;
                $fail_message = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
```

**I have enough updated max_post_size, memory_limit, max_upload_size in php.ini file.**

Comment: Sidenote: http://bobby-tables.com - Learn about prepared statements for more security. real_escape_string isn't enough to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

The default PHP values are 2 MB for upload_max_filesize, and 8 MB for post_max_size. Depending on your host, changing these two PHP variables can be done in a number of places with the most likely being php.ini or .htaccess (depending on your hosting situation).
You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

> ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
>
> upload_max_filesize = 40M (ex. 40MB and you can change more size)
>
> ; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
>
> post_max_size = 40M (ex. 40MB and you can change more size)

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

Comment: I have tried changing these. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Error is like in $_POST['title'], index (i.e., title) is undefined. It is not set while sending post from html form itself.

Comment: try give isset like this echo isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "No tittle"; maybe no detected your post

Comment: Actually I tried printing the post array and there is no title in that only.